# In which way would the yeast cell cope with the excess amount of methionine in the growth media? 

Tags: biochemistry, metabolism, toxicology

I guess that when there is surplus of methionine in the cell it is incorporated in the TCA cycle as a succinyl CoA, with cysteine as a by-product. But now the cell has the surplus of cysteine. What does it do with it? How does it remove excess sulphur from the cell? Would that process somehow influence NAD<sup>+</sup>/NADH balance?

Comment: Is there any evidence that methionine is toxic to yeast?

Comment: I know there are some strains of yeast that are unable to form colonies on the medium that has high concentration of methionine in it. I have reformulated the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In humans, cysteine first fills the glutathione pool (which itself is a reservoir for cysteine, apart from reduction equivalents and biotransformation). Excess cysteine can go three ways,

1. [oxidation to sulfoalanine and further hypotaurine and taurine](http://www.reactome.org/cgi-bin/eventbrowser?DB=gk_current&ID=1614645), via still unknown enzyme(s)
2. [degradation to lanthionine and toxic H<sub>2</sub>S](http://www.reactome.org/cgi-bin/eventbrowser?DB=gk_current&ID=1614591)
3. [degradation to serine and toxic H<sub>2</sub>S](http://www.reactome.org/cgi-bin/eventbrowser?DB=gk_current&ID=1614614)

Since cystathionine gamma lyase which (its L-cysteine desulfhydrase activity) catalyses 2 and 3 has homologues in yeast, my guess is that H<sub>2</sub>S is produced there too. [Further oxidation of H<sub>2</sub>S](http://www.reactome.org/cgi-bin/eventbrowser?DB=gk_current&FOCUS_SPECIES=Homo%20sapiens&ID=1614517&) happens through an ancient mitochondrial pathway which is highly conserved as well, yielding sulfite and sulfate. Sulfate then makes for a bit acidic environment but else is non-toxic.

I have linked to reactome.org entries where you can find references. Filling up the yeast's glutathione pool (if it happens) would move the NAD<sup>+</sup>/NADH balance to the NADH side, i.e., fill up reduction equivalents, too.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to reactome.org. Wasn't aware of it :)